# Can I see Dota 2 game info online?

Tags: dota-2

My brother just played Dota 2. For once he's done well, and I want to see if the team carried him.

ID: 184114837

Can anyone show me how to pull up match info based on the ID without having to launch the game? (i.e via web-browser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can search dota 2 games by ID on **dotabuff.com**

Here is your [game](http://dotabuff.com/matches/184114837) ... and it's pretty obvious why they won xD

However you won't see all the player names so you will have to know what hero he played,due the option in dota 2 to make your games publicly visible.

Comment: He played as Skeleton King, but clearly PL did carry. Although despite that, it seems he did do something useful for once. (hes usually 0-12 lol.) Especially with BS and PA not playing great. Whwat was huskar even doing. Id say he had it easy.

Comment: How many carries in dat game ?

Comment: @Doomsknight Looks to be a very solid game for SK, even if PL carried harder. Also looks like Husk abandoned at L4 (no skill ups after that) and probably died a lot from the team playing him with a 5m level disadvantage. Short game, though - PL seems to have rushed to Manta Style, so it must have started going well pretty early. 12-53(59) says a lot. Their early game Pudge looks like he didn't know his hero too well, and the team failed to hold out long enough for Medusa to become useful. I'd have to see the replay to get a solid sense of the key moments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use http://dotabuff.com/ (just search the match ID) to get a nice summary of the match.

The nickname won't always be displayed since each player can choose whether or not he wants to make its profile public (you'll need to know what hero your brother picked).

Comment: Thanks. Other guy answered just before you, but none the less, good answer. +1